# Navigation Bar and TableView, a row deletion causes a bug?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationbar

I'm just working on a little App and discovered an annoying visual bug. I will put the Screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, as you can see I just remove a row from the table view.
In the second and third picture you can see that the navigation bar is blurred red in the lower right corner.
In the fourth picture the blur has tone away, but just because I scrolled the table view.

Now my question: Is that a bug? And if yes or no, how can I make the blur disappear without scrolling the tableview (That it wouldn't be blurred in the third picture)?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is running on iPhone Simulator iOS 7.1 Beta 5. It just happens for the first row.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? The UINavigationBar in 7.0.3 and below behaves a little different.